# Gauss manin connection under base change?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Consider for a proper smooth projective morphism f: X--> S-->spec(k), A is a regular k algebra of finite type , S=spec(A), k is a field .

we know that for$ R^n f_*(\Omega ^._{X/S})$ we have a Gauss manin connection$\nabla$.

And then for a k morphism g:T-->S ,we have a base change .

So what is the relation between the Gauss manin connection of the original and  the one after base change. what about in the special situation  when T =spec (L), L is the fraction field of A?

Comment: Presumably you meant to assume $S$ is smooth over $k$, not just regular (in case $k$ has nonzero characteristic). Given your initial setup, do you mean to assume $T$ is also smooth over $k$?  Asking about the function field of $S$ violates your finite type hypothesis on the base over $k$, so what is it you really want to know about that?  

Comment: k is zero characteristic . you can have nice assumption on T and the map g ,it is not the key point here .  

Comment: OK, so using the construction of the Gauss-Manin connection as in Katz-Oda and the functoriality of the deRham complex, it drops out by inspection of the definitions that the connection is compatible with the base change morphism on higher direct image. In char. 0 the formation of the higher direct images even commutes with base change. Is there more one could want?

Comment: what is the exact meaning for "the connection is compatible with the base change morphism"?
For example ,in the special  case , T is the generi point of S  ,say  h:$X_T$   -->T-->spec(k),suppose we have a section t of $R^n h_*(X_T / T)$  ,and we extend it into a section $s$ of $R^n f_*(X/S)$ , and suppose ,$\nabla^' ( s )=0$, is it implies that $\nabla ( t )=0$ ?

Comment: TOM, once again if you take $T$ to be the generic point then you violate your hypotheses that the base is finite type over $k$.  If you just want to work Zariski-locally then all it says is that the construction is local on the base.  I assumed you were interested in base change $g$ more subtle than open immersions.  Please clarify, and then I can provide a definition appropriate to the generality you wish to have. 

Comment: But to have a Gauss manin connection ,you don't have to assume T is finite type over k, you just need it to be smooth.And my hypotheses is just about A ,it does not mean that the base spce should always be finite type .And this situatin is just what I want ,it is the situation in the proof of Deligne-milne's paper "Hodge cycles on abelian varieties"section 2,proposition2.5 

Comment: TOM, strictly speaking "smooth" requires being (locally) of finite presentation, which the generic point basically never satisfies, so you mean "essentially smooth"; anyway, that's just word games, so not important. The meaning of the compatibility I asserted is that under the base change maps ${\rm{R}}^n f_ {\ast}(X/S) \rightarrow g_ {\ast} {\rm{R}}^n h_ {\ast}(X_ T/T)$ and $\Omega^1_ {X/S} \rightarrow g_ {\ast} \Omega^1_ {X_ T/T}$, $\nabla_ f(c)$ goes to $\nabla_ h(g^{\ast}(c))$. For example, the answer to your "generic stalk" question is "yes" (and all seen by staring at the construction).

Comment: Great! Thank you for your help!By the way , is there paper or book that I can find the detail proof of your statement ? Or the proof  is just obvious?

Comment: @TOM: To me it is obvious from staring at how the connection is constructed (e.g., by the method in the unique Katz-Oda paper) and knowing general functorial behavior of Hodge to deRham spectral sequence with respect to pullback. If it is not obvious to you then you should look more closely at the construction and figure out the functorial properties of hypercohomology and deRham complex with respect to pullback.  (EGA 0_{III}, sections 12.1--12.2 may be illuminating.) 